# What Would Be The Best Order to Watch the Star Wars Animated Content

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order

The shows I am talking about are:

Star Wars: The Clone Wars, Star Wars: Rebels, Star Wars Animated Adventures: Droids, Star Wars: Resistance, Star Wars: Ewoks, and Star Wars: Forces of Destiny.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you mention Clone Wars, you are referring to the CGI rendered version and not the non-canon Gennedy Tartakovsky version, correct?

Comment: @Machavity with a "the" it is the official name of the 3D one—without is the official name of the earlier one.

Comment: @Machavity-I think so, yes. The Tartakovsky version is the animated movie, right?

Comment: @Gothamite24 No, it's one that's a cartoon, rather than the one that's a 3D animation.

Comment: So, there are 2 Clone Wars animated series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Droids* and *Ewoks* are not available to watch, as far as I'm aware. There was never an official DVD release of the entirety of either series, only a few episodes, and in any case they're no longer considered Canon and as such are unlikely to ever be rereleased. However, if you get your hands on the two DVD releases that included a pair of TV-movie-edits of eight episodes from either series, they'd both be set between the end of *The Clone Wars* and Episode IV; they'd have nothing to do with any of the other released shows, since they aren't canon anymore.

As for the rest, the best order is probably chronological as follows:

***Star Wars: The Clone Wars*** (A number of episodes of this show were created and/or aired out of chronological order, including the animated precursor film of the same title, which can be slightly confusing when an episode set during a particular battle is shown long after that battle ended in a previous episode. There are chronological-order episode lists available online, or you can just watch them by airdate.)

***Star Wars: Rebels*** (This takes place between Episode III and IV; characters and events from the Prequel and Original Trilogies as well as *The Clone Wars* are present.)

***Star Wars: Resistance*** (This takes place between Episode VI and VII; a couple of characters from both the Original and Sequel Trilogies make appearances.)

***Forces of Destiny*** is a little different, since episodes may take place across all eras of *Star Wars*, so I'd suggest just watching them all together after *Resistance*.

Comment: The reason i was asking about Droids and Ewoks is there is actually a website where you can watch cartoons online, and they are on that list, which is why i was asking.

Comment: Well that sounds like a pirate site and since the entire shows were never released, I can't imagine they'd have all the episodes. I'd probably stay away from there if I were you, but if you really want to risk it, they *would* have been set between The Clone Wars and Episode IV, if they still counted.

Comment: Just had a quick look on the UK Amazon site and if it's the same series being referred to, both Ewoks and Droids are available on DVD

Comment: @SpacePhoenix There was a DVD release quite a few years ago that compiled two TV-movie-edited sets of four episodes of either series, but it's long out of print. Neither release has the complete series.

Comment: A comment to confirm the order of The Clone Wars and Rebels.  I recently started binging Rebels, and there are several events that resulted in me wishing I had binged The Clone Wars first.